# Joint test for absolute value of a mean

Tags: hypothesis-testing

How can I test than the mean of a variable is greater than or equal to -3 and less than or equal to 3?
In other words I want to test if the absolute value of the mean is less than or equal to 3.
Thanks!!

Comment: Welcome, Laurie.  If you wish to clarify or otherwise modify a question and it has not been answered yet, then please feel free to edit it.